# display URL or permalink instead of page title in dashboard

Tags: permalinks, urls, dashboard

Is there a way to display the page url or permalink instead of the page title on

```
example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page
```

I am doing some A/B testing and some pages have the same title, but a different URL.

Also I may experiment from time to time with a different title. I know all my pages by URL and would prefer to see this in the list of pages.

Answer (score 2):

Filter `'the_title'` on the screen with the list table of your post type.
The pattern for the initial hook is: `manage_edit-post_type_name_columns`.

Sample code:

```
// replace 'post' with the post type name you want to catch.
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'wpse_67171_title_to_url' );

/**
 * Replace the default title with its permalink.
 *
 * @param  string $title
 * @param  int $id Post ID
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_67171_title_to_url( $title, $id = 0 )
{
    if ( 'the_title' !== current_filter() )
    {
        add_filter( 'the_title', __FUNCTION__, 10, 2 );
        return $title;
    }
    // strip domain name
    return parse_url( get_permalink( $id ), PHP_URL_PATH );
}
```

Result:

[image]